# php in array not working for dynamicaly array

Tags: php, arrays, yii

I am trying to print "Backed" when user id is in array.
Here is my code:

```
$backId = app()->user->model()->id;
$backers = MProjectBacker::model()->findAll('projectId=:pid', array(':pid' => $data->id));

foreach ($backers as $b) {
    if (in_array($backId, $b, true)) {
        echo "Backed!";
    } else {
        echo "Not Backed!";
    }
}
```

But no result and no error.

Comment: Delete the true inside your in_array function

Comment: Is $backers multidimensional array (array of arrays)? Check types of values (string or number). You have set third parameter of in_array() to true, so types must be the same, too...

Comment: Yes the backers is multidimensional array and type of value is string

Comment: Ok, so $b is array then (with string values), And $backId is string, too, i guess?  Well... Someone who have experience with YII will help you in that case....

Comment: yes $backId is string too,OK thank you!

Comment: If the problem is solved, please answer yourself so this question could be considered resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"If the third parameter strict is set to TRUE then the in_array() function will also check the types of the needle in the haystack."

But why use in_array function to this?

Why dont you just check the field where you store the $backId?

```
foreach ($backers as $b) {
    if ( (int) $b['fieldNameWhereYouStoreTheBackId'] == (int) $backId ) {
        echo "Backed!";
    }
    else {
        echo "Not Backed!";
    }
}
```

Comment: printing "Backed" for all project

Comment: Could you please send the results of

echo '<pre>';
print_r($backers);

Comment: And var_dump($backId);

Comment: Thank You!solved with your answer and debugging my code!

Comment: What was the problem?